# My checkin dialog for members is too complex (membership web app)

Tags: info-visualisation, dialog

I'm trying to improve my checkin dialog, because it think it's too cluttered.

I think that all of this information is required, but it isn't shown in a simple way that isn't confusing the user.

So i'm looking for better ways to implement this information..

Any thoughts?!
(the web application is in dutch, but i have described the different elements for your convenience).

[image]

Comment: The screenshot doesn't give an idea of the taskflow. So in lack of context, I'd recommend to perform something like [layout analysis, PDF](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=54253FE6E2CA1B2692215FD50FA2D53D?doi=10.1.1.28.9230&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You're right, that dialog is confusing.  I'm not quite sure what the need is here from the user's perspective.  You mention it is a "check-in", so I am assuming that either this dialog is displayed every time a user logs in, or it is displayed only when they click a button/link somewhere else on the site.

So the natural question is, what does the user need to accomplish when the check-in?  I don't see many users needing to see their last 5 purchases when they check-in.  That information should be in a different page/dialog.  I'm also unsure of how much value the "notes" textarea provides.  How is that information used in other places?  If it is not that important, get rid of it.

My guess is that the Number of Turns is likely the important thing here.  I'm confused to why there is an option to select more than one turn to decrement, but I'm sure you had a reason for it.  So what happens when the user has 0 turns left, or will be left with 0 turns after they decrement the current amount?  This is where I think the purchase options come in.

So my suggestion is to determine either what the user is trying to do here, or what you want them to do here.  If you want them to purchase a turn card or subscription card, then structure the dialog to show that the user is running out of turns and should make a purchase to keep going. And anything in the dialog that is not directly related to either what the user is trying to do, or what you want them to do, should be removed.